# Where can I watch a game with New England Patriots fans in NYC?

Tags: new-york-city, football

Is there a gathering place in New York City where Pats fans can assemble in peace for a game?

Comment: New York is a huge city, you should narrow this down a little bit. Maybe to one of the boroughs?

Comment: A [Yelp search](http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=patriots+bar&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY) turns up no fewer than 254 possibilities. You don't indicate what kind of atmosphere or price range or beer list or neighborhood or specials or menu options or anything else you're looking for, which makes it virtually impossible to answer here, especially as "review" answers are often opinion-based and become outdated very quickly. You'll probably find a better answer on a site for Pats fans.

Comment: Sorry, dumb question. I was drinking and interneting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tir na nOg Times Square at 315 W. 39th St. has a huge gathering of Patriots fans every week. It had about 60 fans last week but it seats 300+, so there's room for everyone and no one has to stand. It's an older and more upscale crowd than at at typical football bar, but the prices are quite reasonable because of the NFL specials.

Here is more info on the group that attends:

https://www.facebook.com/NewEnglandPatriotsNYC